# Redirect print python output to a file, when started by a cron job

Tags: python, linux, cron, output

Cron rows:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/python /home/pi/main.py & >> /home/pi/log.txt 2>&1
@reboot whoami >> log2.txt
```

> Both Skripts started!
>   Both files are created!

In log2.txt stands the user pi.
But log.txt stays empty. When i start the python script by a console, then the output of the python script is shown on the console.

What is wrong, that the output don't be written to the file?

I also tried the cronjob by root, the same result

Answer (score 0):

Change to.

/usr/local/python /home/pi/main.py 2>&1 >> /home/pi/log.txt

Comment: I will try it tomorrow, but i need the "&" behind the python skript, so that the script will run background:
@reboot /usr/local/python /home/pi/main.py & 2>&1 >> /home/pi/log.txt
?

Comment: Start a `service`, `cron` is not the proper way to do it. Keep in mind, `cron` will do it repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

```
def log(who, type, debug_level, msg, ip = ""):
if (debug_level <= DEBUG):
    with open('/home/pi/log.txt','a+') as f:
        if (ip != ""):            
            f.write(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime()) + " - " + who + " - " + ip + ": " + type + msg + '\n')
        f.write(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime()) + " - " + who + " - " + type + msg + '\n')
```

I will write direct to a file in the log function.